Best anode surface dimension in copper electrolysis
I want to build 500 amps copper electrolysis refining cell, it composed of 6 cathodes with dimension 420mmx330mm, and 7 bars for anodes, the cell based on calculation it should dissolve 350 grams of anode per hour incase I installed 7 anodes so 6 cathode with two faces collect copper ions.
But ...
Not always I have enough anode copper to fully use the capacity of the cell, I use this cell mainly to collect precious metals that exists in the anode slims, so I want to finish dissolving the anode bars as soon as possible, can I make small anodes and hang them onto the anode busbars and get same results of using anodes with surface area equal to the cathode surface area? I mean for example cast copper anodes with only 300mm x 8mm ( cathode is 420mm x 330mm) is it ok or there is something critical with the anode surface area?
